Energy below threshold energy in photoelectric effect
In the photoelectric effect we shine photons onto a metal surface and if the frequency is greater than some threshold frequency photoelectrons are emitted and the energy of the photons is converted to kinetic energy of the emitted electrons.
My question is what happens when the frequency is less than this threshold frequency? The photons still transfer energy to the metal but no electrons are emitted, so where is energy going?

You should clarify your question. The frequency of what, the energy of what?

Hi, I've just edited your question to try and get it reopened. If you don't like my edit please feel free to roll it back.

If you shine light on a metal most of it is simply reflected because most metals have a reflectivity of $95\%$ or greater. For the $5\%$ of photons that are not reflected photoelectron creation is surprisingly efficient. For example photomultiplier tubes use photoelectron emission to detect light and they can have quantum efficiencies of up to $35\%$.
The trouble is that the photoelectrons are created moving in the same direction as the photon i.e. down into the metal instead of upwards towards the surface. We only see a photoelectron emitted from the surface if that initial photoelectron scatters off other electrons in the metal and ends up moving back towards the surface. These scattering processes spread out the energy over the electron(s) involved in the scattering, so even for frequencies well above the threshold the photoelectron has less kinetic energy than the possible maximum. This is a surprisingly inefficient process, and indeed overall only about one photoelectron for every $10^5$ to $10^6$ photons is emitted.
The energy of the emitted electrons ends up as:
$$ KE = h\nu - \phi - \Delta E$$
where $\Delta E$ is the energy lost in the scattering. In the case of photons below the threshold all the photon energy ends up in that $\Delta E$ term.
So what happens to that energy $\Delta E$? The conduction electrons in the metal carrying that energy repeatedly scatter off other conduction electrons and the energy ends up spread throughout the metal as heat.
So the short answer to your question is that below the threshold frequency all of the photon energy absorbed is converted to heat. But as I said, bear in mind that even above the threshold frequency most of the absorbed photon energy is converted to heat.

I assume this is about the photoelectric effect, correct? The photoelectric effect is a kind of radiation-matter interaction between a photon and a bound electron, but there are many kinds of radiation-matter interactions. In the case of photons, some important ones are: pair production, photoelectric effect, Thomson scattering, Rayleigh scattering and Compton scattering.
If the photon's energy is not enough to excite a transition then typically there will be some kind of scattering process. Thresholds for the photoelectric effect to take place are around $\sim 1-10$ eV. This energy is $\ll m_ec^2$, that implies a couple things. First, pair-production won't happen since that requires a threshold energy $2m_ec^2$. Second, Compton scattering is also unlikely (incoherent scattering) since that usually also involves energy at least in the keV range. Meaning the two most likely interactions of the photon with the material are Thomson scattering and Rayleigh scattering. Both are a kind of coherent scattering, but Thomson scattering involves only one of the electrons while Rayleigh scattering involves the atom as a whole. This kind of scattering event will simply redirect the photon in another direction without changing it's energy.
Depending on the energy scale you also have to account for such things as rotational and vibrational transitions that may absorb photons, and probably many other effects I'm simply not remembering currently.

(+1) Can you elaborate why the cutoff threshold of the photoelectric effect is not clean as a cliff e.g. in https://www.flickr.com/photos/coachrobbo/3909285882 ? Suppose a Big Mac costs 5.58, and we send out 100 children each having 6.00. Then we should have 100 Big Macs at the end, right? If we send out 100 children each having E=hf=5.00, then we should end up with 0 Bic Macs, clean and simple. The diffuse cutoff seems to suggest that the energy of a photon is not tightly determined even if we control the frequency carefully, i.e. photons of same frequency can have different energies?

... If so, then from $E = \sqrt{m_0^2c^4 + p^2c^2}$, it seems that the culprit for this uncertainty in $E$ could only be either different $p$ (i.e. different velocities), or different $m_0$ (i.e. different mass flavors)?

Why are you saying it's a diffuse cutoff? It's not, if the required energy is $4$ eV and you send in $3$ eV photons, you'll never achieve the photoelectric effect. The difference in the curves and in the stopping voltage here have to do with differing intensities and frequencies. For the same frequency but different intensity, the stopping voltage is the same. But if you lower the frequency (however, still above the required energy), the photoelectrons have less available kinetic energy so the stopping voltage is lower.

thank you. I was aiming to argue that $E$ of a photon is not well-defined, and I think I found a better argument why this might be so ( https://www.quora.com/The-energy-of-a-photon-is-determined-by-its-frequency-Does-this-mean-that-all-photons-have-the-same-wave-amplitude ), would you agree that the complete description of the energy of a photon is not entirely captured by its frequency number, as in $E=hf$?
